# Old (1950s?) paperback featuring insect-sized people battling insects, and main characters named 'Clever' and 'Tall'

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for a paperback I read as a kid. The cover had two insect-sized men battling a praying mantis with spears. They also fought ants and termites and cut earthworms into huge steaks. They used the venom of various insects to help in their battles. Tall and Clever were the two main characters.

The twist at the end was their discovery of a dead, normal-sized human skeleton, which they believed to be a deity. Thought Frank Herbert was the author but can’t find this book in his works list. Would likely have been published in the fifties. Fun book and I loved the twist at the end.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies the book you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pretty sure this is ***[The Insect Warriors](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3131148-the-insect-warriors)*** (1965) by Rex Dean Levie.

From Goodreads:

> Tall was a hunter-explorer, venturing off the tiny island fortress of his tribe and making his way through wilderness inhabited only by giant insects ten sizes the size of a man. Loosely protected by chitin-armor, and striking with a spear doubly-barbed with spider venom, Tall fought to find a new home for his people.
> But as he roamed he became more and more aware that mankind was a stranger in this insect world, that there were no other creatures remotely like men. Then where had his people come from?
> As he followed the trail of the almost-mythical Ten who founded his tribe, Tall found more and more mysteries - and death in more forms than he had ever imagined.

From a [reader review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/465817799?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1):

> The concept of tiny people in a giant world might not be new, but underlying concept for The Insect Warriors is fresh and interesting. It is a real shame that we have to trudge through the entire book to only scratch the surface of what is really going on in the world during the last 15 pages. It’s also a real shame that the author decided to name their characters based on their attributes. **Tall is named Tall because he is literally tall, Clever because he is literally clever, and these names seem to be passed on from father to son.**

[image]

Comment: Beat me by four minutes.